# BackboneJS: Check username

Tags: api, backbone.js, model

I'm using BackboneJS and I have a model called "username".

I'd like to send a request to my API to check if the username in my model is available on my database.

```
var usernameModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/api/users/username_available',
    defaults: {
        username: ''
    },
    checkUsername: function() {
        //Check username from the api
    }
}
```

My question is very basic. What I have to do to check my username? What is the best practise here? Call the function this.save()? (not really a saving...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need to do this with backbone, I think its just an Ajax call and it will be crear what you are doing in that method, this way your model can grow in fields and the checkusername method just does that, and does not mess with the other fields that you will probably add later or maybe not given that the model its called username.

```
checkUsername: function() {
    $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json', 
         data: {usernameParam: username},
         complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
         //called when complete

         },
         success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
         //called when successful
         },
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         //called when there is an error
         }
    });
 }
```

Comment: And you could even make it a class method on your User model.